# How to find the index of a facet of a boundary mesh region closest to a given point?

Tags: computational-geometry, mesh, nearest

Using the `RegionNearest[]` function, it is possible to calculate the point, $p_{mesh}$, on a mesh region that is nearest to some input point, $p_{input}$. My question is: how to calculate the (label of the) triangle to which the point $p_{mesh}$ is associated?

For example using trial and error I can work out that triangle number 20 contains the point on the mesh which is nearest to my test point.

```
a = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 1], 
   MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> 1}, PrecisionGoal -> 1];
testpoint = {1.0, 0.2, 0.7};
pt = RegionNearest[a, testpoint]
Show[{HighlightMesh[a, Style[{2, 20}, Orange, Opacity[0.5]]], 
  Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[testpoint]}], 
  Graphics3D[{Blue, PointSize[Large], Point[pt]}]}]
```

[image: Exampleimage of mesh and nearest points]

Is there any built in functionality for this in Mathematica? I can imagine a round about way of doing this by finding in the list of vertices of the mesh, which three points are closest to $p_{mesh}$ and then working out which triangle they are associated to. This seems to be too convoluted somehow. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Naive solution:

```
Catch[If[RegionMember[MeshPrimitives[a, #], pt], Throw[#]] & /@ 
  MeshCellIndex[a, 2]]
```

> {2, 20}

Comment: This looks good, many thanks! I will wait before accepting to see if there are any other options like undocumented features in the `RegionNearest` function.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the built-in (undocumented) function `` Region`Mesh`MeshNearestCellIndex ``:

```
nearestcellindex = Region`Mesh`MeshNearestCellIndex[a, testpoint]
```

> ```
> {2, 20}
> ```

```
np = RegionNearest[a, testpoint];

Show[{HighlightMesh[a, 
   Style[nearestcellindex, Orange, Opacity[0.5]], 
   PlotTheme -> "Lines"], 
  Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[testpoint], 
    Purple, Point @ np, 
    Black, Dashed, Line[{testpoint, np} ]}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: see also: [this Q/A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/188686/125)